# Get used to + Be used to

Tags: past-tense, past-habitual

I'd like to ask what the meaning of these two following sentences is:

1. I am used to smoking
2. I get used to smoking

It looks the same to me but what is the reason that we generate verbs by using “get”?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the second sentence wouldn't normally be phrased in the way that you've phrased it. Depending on the tense, it would more commonly take one of these forms:

> I will get used to smoking.
>   I am getting used to smoking.
>   I got used to smoking.

---

> 1. I am used to smoking.

This is a simple statement of fact.

> 2. I get used to smoking.

This describes an activity, a process that you engage in. Once you have *finished* getting used to smoking, you will *be* used to smoking.

Comment: This answer is great. Thank you so much!